# Ecmascript Abstract Equality Comparison

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

The ECMAScript specification for "abstract equality comparison" (`==`) has changed between the 6.0 and 9.0 versions, adding an `!` character in front of the `ToNumber` calls in some of the components of the comparison. Can someone tell me why ECMAScript has added this to the spec? It's so confusing.

Here's the version of the spec from 6.0:
[image: 6.0]
And here's how the spec has changed in 9.0:
[image: 9.0]
What motivated this change? What does it mean?

Comment: There are two images to describe my question, please look for.

Comment: Why did you take pictures of *text*?

Comment: em...,sorry, I am not so familiar about using stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you just copy the text and paste here?

Comment: @Amy In this case, taking a screenshot and highlighting the difference by painting arrows might be better and easier than trying to transcribe the spec document into markdown. The screenshots should have been accompanied by hyperlinks to the respective spec sections, though.

Answer (score 2):

See [Notational Conventions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-notational-conventions), specifically [ReturnIfAbrupt Shorthands](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands):

> Similarly, prefix `!` is used to indicate that the following invocation
>   of an abstract or syntax-directed operation will never return an
>   abrupt completion and that the resulting Completion Record's [[Value]]
>   field should be used in place of the return value of the operation.
>   For example, the step:
>
> 1. Let `val` be `!` `OperationName()`.
>
> is equivalent to the following steps:
>
> 1. Let `val` be `OperationName()`.
> 2. Assert: `val` is never an abrupt completion.
> 3. If `val` is a Completion Record, set `val` to `val`.[[Value]].
>
> Syntax-directed operations for runtime semantics make use of this
>   shorthand by placing `!` or `?` before the invocation of the operation:
>
> 1. Perform `!` SyntaxDirectedOperation of NonTerminal.